# Do I "access" or "get access to"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

These days we can *access* more and more online systems. However, should we say *access* or *get access to* as in the following example:

> - You can *access* your account by clicking this link.
> - You can *get access to* your account by clicking this link.

I personally prefer the *access* form, but I'm afraid I might be making a mistake and the proper form is *get access to*.

Also, are **continuous** forms of *access* and *get access to* allowed e.g.

> - I am *accessing* my account now
> - I am *getting access to* my account now

Which is correct?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As for me, *Getting access* would mean *Obtaining credentials*. You click this link to have an OTP or a token or a password sent to you. After you *got access*, you can use it to *access* the account itself.

Same with continuous:

> - I am *accessing* my account now, logging into it and about to start using it (or even using it right now)
> - I am *getting access* to my account, I'm on the phone with the administrator and they are resetting my password, or making sure my current IP is allowed through the firewall.