# Are these two sentences both grammatically correct?

Tags: usage

Are these two sentences both grammatically correct? If so, which one sounds more natural?

- This way of getting to understand Leśniewski is the one I would recommend.
- This way to understand Leśniewski is the one I would recommend

Answer (score 3):

To me, the sentences have slightly different meanings.

I would understand the first one as recommending a way of teaching yourself about Lesniewski's theories.

The second could be recommending a particular interpretation of his work.

Comment: related: [Do I "access" or "get access to"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/725/do-i-access-or-get-access-to)

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong with the grammar here.

However, the first example is very informal. Using the verb **to get** is the problem. It would be better to say **obtain an understanding of**.  Using **get** this way is fine in informal speech, but in formal writing you should avoid it if possible.

The second example means something different, and I agree with Kate Butning's answer here, so I won't repeat that.